# Special characters in AWS Athena show up as question marks

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, ddl, amazon-athena, presto

I've added a table in AWS Athena from a csv file, which uses special characters "æøå". These show up as � in the output. 
The csv file is encoded using unicode. I've also tried changing the encoding to UTF-8, with no luck. 
I've uploaded the csv in S3 and then added the table to Athena using the following DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `regions_dk`(
  `postnummer` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `kommuner` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `regioner` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'separatorChar'='\;') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/path'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv')
```

I have another table which also includes the characters "æøå", which I added using an ETL script, and here there's no issue.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: I suggest base64 encoding the text, if you find no better solution :)

Comment: Are you sure the file encoding was UTF-8? Just tried with characters included in you example and works as expected. However if I create the csv in my Excel running on WIN 10 (the default encoding isn't UTF-8) I'm getting those unexpected characters you mentioned.

Comment: @PeterKoncz - Yeah, for some reason I got the encoding wrong. I thought I changed in to UTF-8, however I messed it up somehow :) Thanks for the reply

Comment: I'm getting the same problem when addying a comment in a column

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded an ANSI encoded file to S3, there was several unreadable data left, I changed the encoding of the file from the PC to UTF-8, I did the process again and everything was fine.

I did it with sublimetext.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).