# Hebrew encoding on AWS Athena \ Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, encoding, aws-glue, amazon-athena, hebrew

I have a CSV file that contains a string with Hebrew letters,
all the Hebrew letters are shown as question marks (like -> `??? ?? ??????`) when I query from Athena.

I tried opening the file in notepad++ and it looks fine and to open it with pandas when adjusting the encoding and it works.

Is it possible to pass the encoding as a parameter either to AWS glue or AWS Athena?

Comment: From what I can see in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783227/special-characters-in-aws-athena-show-up-as-question-marks#comment98318596_51783227) [cases](https://big-data-demystified.ninja/2018/07/22/gibberish-in-aws-athena-instead-of-hebrew/), the issue is usually that the original file is not UTF-8 encoded, so be 100% sure that it is. Then, answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403071/text-files-uploaded-to-s3-are-encoded-strangely) may help.